# Joining Together Javascript Object Members?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Given any object with members that look like this:

```
target
{
    x1 : 1
    x2 : 2
    x3 : 3
    y1 : 6
    y2 : 5
    y3 : 4
}
```

I need to transform the object into something like this:

```
target
{
    x : [1, 2, 3]
    y : [6, 5, 4]
}
```

From the basic JavaScript I know, it seems like the following function would work:

```
function joinParameters(target, paramName) {
    var count = 1;
    var array = [];
    var name = paramName.concat(count);
    var value = target[name];
    while (typeof value != undefined) {
        array.push(value);
        name = paramName.concat(count);
    }
    target[paramName] = array;
}
```

So, I could say joinParameters(target, "x"); The problem, however, is that

```
    var value = target[name];
```

is always undefined. I followed the code in FireBug to make sure that the target object has the property that I'm trying to get, and it does. So, I'm not quite sure what's wrong.

If jQuery has an elegant way of doing this, then I would prefer that solution.

Comment: Do you mean to use `.join` instead of `.concat`? `.concat` will return an array, and `.join` will return a string.

Comment: i think he meant to do a substr actually.. because paramName is a string

Comment: The String object has a concat method too. It was definitely concatenating the strings correctly when I was stepping through the code. ref: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_concat_string.asp

Comment: w3schools has a lot of misleading and incorrect information, it's best not to use it as a reference.

Comment: Really? I had no idea... is there a comprehensive reference that you recommend?

Comment: 'The' reference is here: http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-262.htm but it's a little hard to read. Mozilla is usually pretty good: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Javascript

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using underscore.js:

```
_(target).keys().reduce(function(memo, key){
    var split = /([^\d]+)([\d]+)/.exec(key);
    memo[split[1]] = memo[split[1]]||[];
    memo[split[1]][parseInt(split[2],10)-1] = target[key];
    return memo;
},{});
```

Working example:

http://jsfiddle.net/PLgN5/

Comment: Thanks, David. I appreciate your answer as well as your helpful comments. Answer accepted.

Answer (score 3):

```
function joinParams(target) {
    var p;

    for (prop in target) {
        p = prop.substr(0, 1);

        if (!target[p]) {
                target[p] = [];
        }

        target[p].push(target[prop]);
    }

    return target;
}

target =
{
    x1 : 1,
    x2 : 2,
    x3 : 3,
    y1 : 6,
    y2 : 5,
    y3 : 4
}

target = joinParams(target);
```

Answer (score 2):

you could do:

```
function joinParams(o) { 
    var ret = {},
        key;
    for(var i in o) {
        key = i.substr(0,1);
        ret[key] = ret[key] ? ret[key].push(o[i]) && ret[key] : [o[i]];
    } 
    return ret;
}


var target = /* original object */
target = joinParams(target);
```

Answer (score 1):

There are some logic errors in your original code (i.e. infinite loop). Fix:

```
function joinParameters(target, paramName) {
    var count = 1;
    var array = [];
    var name = paramName.concat(count);
    var value = target[name];
    while (value != undefined) {   /* typeof value will return "undefined". */
        array.push(value);
        /* You need to increment 'count'. */
        name = paramName.concat(++count);
        value = target[name];
    }
    target[paramName] = array;
}

...

joinParameters(target, "x");
```

Note this function call will add a new element `x` to `target`, `x1, x2, ..., x6` will still exist in `target`. In fact, this function doesn't take care of the `y` element, which I assume you want to "join" as well.

For a more versatile function, the answer by *zachallia* should do the trick.

Comment: Ugh, yeah, I should have seen that... I only stepping through the first part of the the code in FireBug and wondering about the failed condition. Thanks!